# Implementing Post API: Client(HTTPURLCONNECTION) : SERVER - Ubuntu using NAT (80 – win10 to 8080 VirtualBox)

Tags: android, http, post

I have to send a Post API using HTTPURLCONNECTION to server. I am using android IDE - developing android application.

---

**Client code:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:80/OServer/RegisterUser");      // this API is working on browser at time I tested
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UFT-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(20);
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
con.setReadTimeout(5000);
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setDoOutput(true);      
con.setDoInput(true);      
con.connect();               // the thread stops at this point. (I know this is not required but I put it just to test and understand how it works)
String value;
value = "abcdefgh";              
//Posting data to server.
BufferedOutputStream wr = new BufferedOutputStream (con.getOutputStream()); // if we do not put Connect() above, the thread will stop here as here we are getting outputstream : it contains Connect automatically.  
wr.write(Byte.valueOf(value));
wr.flush();
wr.close();
// end of post
//fetching response code
int code = con.getResponseCode(); // if we put this above Post, the thread stops itself there. I can assume that any actual connection to server is not being served.
//I never tested below as I got stuck above 
//fetching the response of server request
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     response.append(inputLine);
  }
in.close();
```

---

**Server Code :**

I have not implemented it but I have set a Status code to at least get response of getResponseCode().
//I have typed below code. It may contain syntax error.
//this method have no annotation used

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND)
}
```

---

I request help for:

1) If I do not have machine have webserver installed and still I send a 127.0.0.1 http client request we get a 101 error. This information is per http response code standards.
Any function say con.connect() does not throw exception. How do we know in android logs what the exact issue is? And how we can handle them as exceptions to prevent the application crash without reason if we are using main thread?

2) Now I have webserver installed on Virtual box (Ubuntu OS - Tomcat server) hosted on win10 OS followed by NAT (80 -->8080). It means I am able to acces server on main machine i.e. Windows

http://127.0.0.1:80/OServer/RegisterUser -- working on web browser
http://127.0.0.1:80/OServer/HelloWorld --  404 - page not found on web browser

Android does not throw any exception. How can I handle page not found exception at client end?

3) Even when I am using working URL as above then also thread stops itself at connect() function. I requested for response code and implemented same on server still I have issues.

Can anyone please guide me with above problems. Also, I am looking for guide / PDF where I can read API development - Post/Get using Java EE with Exception handling, common problems , things we should keep in mind for better performance.

I request for help / advise/ documents link / any guidance. I will appreciate. Happy Java Coding.

### :-)

Comment: Try your urls on a browser on your device first. See if a connection is established. And of course you cannot use 127.0.0.1.

Comment: If you cannot connect or if your app crashes you will have exception(s). You will find them in the logcat. Please post them.

Comment: `how we can handle them as exceptions to prevent the application crash without reason if we are using main thread?`. That is nonsense. You should not execute network code on the main thread to begin with.

Comment: Thankyou... My connection was established on browser using localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1

Comment: Why cannot be use 127.0.0.1 - my server is hosted on local machine on which I also have client (server is inside virtual box using NAT). So I must be using either localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Dude .. I am not getting any exceptions .. even not 404.. It seems it has some other issue. I am absolutely not asking rubbish question.. Rather I believe no question is rubbish.. It just the state why it was raised by an individual.. Anyway thanx for information.

Comment: `My connection was established on browser using localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1 ` That was a browser on your pc. But you should use a browser on your device or emulator. It is unclear if you use a device or an emulator to run your Android app.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address of your emulator. And of your android device. And every android phone. And every pc on earth. Like localhost is. Every device is its own localhost.

Comment: I find this logical .. This may be the issue.. I shall check and respond.. Thanks

Comment: I used my system IP (found using ipconfig) : it is working on browser. I replaced 127.0.0.1 to that in android code. But still the same. No exception is generated for 404 which I get on browser using url : http://192.168.56.1/CServer/HelloWorld (this servlet is not on server) - Surely I take you point in my pad. I shall follow this. Thanks. Please suggest something else which may be missing.

Comment: Repeat: `It is unclear if you use a device or an emulator to run your Android app`.

Comment: I am using a emulator. As by Android Studio.

Comment: `IP (found using ipconfig) : it is working on browser. `. From which device? Use a browser on your emulator.

Comment: My emulator does not have internet setup. This may be the issue.. I should check this in code? Do I have anything to check this? I have not given permission to use Internet. Do we require permission to do so?

Comment: Please answer: `From which device? Use a browser on your emulator. `. Why do i have to ask twice?

Comment: `My emulator does not have internet setup.` It is unclear what you mean by that. I cannot remember i ever had to set up internet for an emulator.

Comment: It is because I am doing this in office and my internet sits behind a proxy. So the proxy does not allow requests from emulator. So I will to set proxy to let it access internet.

Comment: Sorry. I will use browser on emulator to check if I am able to access API get request. Second I am using custom AVD : I have not choser emulator specific to any mobile. To check performance I have kept RAM 512.